# frequently getting input parameters of rest api as empty over http

Tags: php, rest, http, https, postman

I have one rest API hosted on domain `https://test.com/api.php`

Input to this rest api is raw json - `{"email":"test@gmail.com"}`

From PHP, I am capturing this raw input using below code :

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

This is working fine if I am hitting to https://test.com/api.php

But when I am trying to hit with http://test.com/api.php, sometimes it is working fine but sometimes I am getting post data as empty

Any Specific known reason for this behavior? Unable to figure out what the issue is.

*I am using postman for API hit.*